# Hide comma if the following word isn't present in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json file with data that gets passed into a component. Some objects have all 3 variables and some have some data missing. We want to display something like:

-Alice, Seattle WA

but if Seattle and WA aren't present we want to display just

-Alice

And vice versa. And hide the hyphen if nothing is present. What's the cleanest way to do this?

```
 <div>
     - {item.name}, {item.city} {item.state}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could resolve this in the following way:

```
 <div>
     - {item.name} { (item.city && item.state) && `, ${item.city} {item.state}` }
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<div>
   - {item.name + (item.city ? ', ' + item.city : '') + (item.state ? ' ' + item.state : '')}
<div>
```

or you could simplify further

```
<div>
   - {item.name} { (item.city && item.state) && `, ${item.city} {item.state}` }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const address = `${item.name}, ${item.city} ${item.state}`
  ? `-${item.name}, ${item.city} ${item.state}`
  : null;
```

Display like this:

{address}